# Android Share Button

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

EDIT*: FOR hovanessyan

```
private String getWheelValue(int id) {
    WheelView wheel = getWheel(R.id.passw_1);
    int index = wheel.getCurrentItem();
    ((ArrayWheelAdapter<String>) wheel.getViewAdapter()).getItemText(index).toString();
    final String values = getWheelValue(R.id.passw_1) + " " + getWheelValue(R.id.passw_2) + " " + getWheelValue(R.id.passw_3);
```

Comment: What is the problem? please explain the problem?

Comment: I have updated my question and code please see EDIT*:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your code will not compile because of :

```
initWheel(R.id.passw_2, new String[] { "Are", "Going", ""Went });
initWheel(R.id.passw_3, new String[] { "There", "Here", ""Away });
```

Your button is not clicking, because in the presented code, you never call `getWheelValue()`

You should get reference to your button and attach onClickListener, in your onCreate() method.

You should start your changes with something like...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.passw_layout);

    initWheel(R.id.passw_1, new String[] { "You", "Me", "Us" });
    initWheel(R.id.passw_2, new String[] { "Are", "Going", "Went" });
    initWheel(R.id.passw_3, new String[] { "There", "Here", "Away" });

    Button mix = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_mix);
    mix.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mixWheel(R.id.passw_1);
            mixWheel(R.id.passw_2);
            mixWheel(R.id.passw_3); 

        }
    });

    Button share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
    share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // call some other methods before that I guess...

           String values = getAllWheelValues();
           startActivity(createEmailIntent(values)); 
    }
    });

}

    private Intent createEmailIntent(String values) { 

           Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
           emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
           emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getResources().getString(R.string.Subject));
           emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, values);

           return emailIntent;
    }
```

EDIT:

I think you should have something like, and call `getAllWheelValues()` in the `onClick()` of share button:

```
private String getAllWheelValues() {
 String val1 = getWheelValue(R.id.passw_1);
 String val2 = getWheelValue(R.id.passw_2);
 String val3 = getWheelValue(R.id.passw_3);

 return val1+" "+val2+" "+val3;
}

private String getWheelValue(int id) {
    WheelView wheel = getWheel(id);
    int index = wheel.getCurrentItem();
    return ((ArrayWheelAdapter<String>) wheel.getViewAdapter()).getItemText(index).toString();
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the code i can see where you are coming from and how to get it to work but its just giving me a few errors could you post the full code with your changes as i cant see where to add after this bit "private String getWheelValue(int id) {" should i leave it at the bottom and just move the button

Comment: I was not able to fully understand what your intentions are. The problem thou is, that you are setting the onClickListener, in a block of code, which is never called. Generally the idea would be to get reference to your button and set the listener in your onCreate() method. After that, in the onClick() you can call whatever methods you want.

Comment: Sorry i will try to explain my self fully first thanks for your help so far, I have the button working now well it clicks and opens up an option to share but i need to set the "values". The code i have so far http://pastebin.com/CPtisp9C. the values are set using the peice of code in my question I have edited but i cant seem where to put it in the java file i have pasted above. Does it need to go before the Button or after?

Comment: I have edited my code, so basically in your onClick() of the share button, you have to call method (probably getWheelValue(), and than passed the returned values to createEmailIntent() so that they are set in the message. I don't know what is the ID you have to pass to getWheelValue();

Comment: Hi hovanessyan if you look at my question that code has to go somewhere to set what will be shown where it says "values" in the emailIntent. If you look at my question you will see the String values are being got from thress wheels passw_1, passw_2, passw_3 i need that code somewhere maybe it could be striped down though?

Comment: yep, see edit. You can use StringBuilder instead of Strings for the "values" etc..hope that helps